# In PowerShell, is there an "on installation" event (for Install-Module)?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

When I define my own module with a manifest, I have the option to run a ps1 upon import of my module (ScriptsToProcess) (Import-Module).

Is there a similar hook for that triggers upon install (Install-Module)?

---

I'm asking because support for the PSData.ExternalModuleDependencies is still super scarse.

I need to trigger an installation of a dependent external module, when I install my own module(s)

Comment: Try using a file in the PS profile directory - `$profileDir = split-path $profile` - check if it exists or create otherwise. I haven't tried it so I'm not posting an answer.

Comment: Installation of what exactly? The module itself?

Comment: edited for clarification